# Hide PandasTable row index

Tags: tkinter, attributes, rowheader, pandastable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6Lqx.png)for display purposes, I would like to hide the row identifier's in pandastable, and I can find no documentation on how this may be possible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hideRowHeader()`

Reference: https://github.com/dmnfarrell/pandastable/issues/230